# Limit the number of characters rendered by a Mustache.js tag

Tags: javascript, mustache

Is there any way in Mustache of limiting the number of characters a Mustache tag generates?

eg

```
template = "<li>{{my_tag}}</li>"

data = {
    "my_tag" : "A very long string that needs to be abbreviated to fit into the available space."
}
```

Now when I render my tag I want to abbreviate the long string by showing only the first 10 chars follwed by an ellipsis. I looked into using a lambda function (as described in the Mustache docs) like so...

```
template = "<li>{{#limitLength}}{{my_tag}}{{/limitLength}}</li>"

data = {
    "limitLength" : function() {
        return function(text) {
          return text.substr(0,10) + '...';
        }
      },
    "my_tag" : "A very long string that needs to be abbreviated to fit into the available space."
}
```

but unfortunately the {{my_tag}} tag doesn't get expanded. The Mustache manual states:

> The text passed is the literal block, unrendered. {{tags}} will not
>   have been expanded - the lambda should do that on its own.

.. but I can't imagine how to do this without using the Mustache.to_html() function and when I try to use it like so...

eg

```
data = {
    "limitLength" : function() {
        return function(text) {
          return Mustache.to_html(text,data).substr(0,10) + '...';
        }
      },
     "my_tag" : "A very long string that needs to be abbreviated to fit into the available space."
}
```

... it fails silently (the recursive use of the data object is possibly to blame here)

Does anyone know of any other way of achieving this without resorting to a javascript/jQuery function, I'd like to implement it just using Mustache if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function actually gets called with two arguments: the unrendered text and a `render` function which can be used to render your text, keeping the current context.

```
data = {
    "limitLength" : function() {
        return function(text, render) {
          return render(text).substr(0,10) + '...';
        }
      },
     "my_tag" : "A very long string that needs to be abbreviated to fit into the available space."
}
```

Comment: You're correct, that works, thanks...but how did you know that was how it worked? The Mustache docs at http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html seem to be incomplete as no mention is made of this render parameter paased to the function. Is there some other more thorough documentation I'm missing or did you just go looking in the Mustach.js lib to discover that? In any case the docs should really be corrected. I created an issue on github. https://github.com/defunkt/mustache/issues/125

Comment: I don't remember where I found out about it, but the README for mustache.js actually does mention it.

Comment: +1 for making an example with `function(text, render)` .. as the mustache 5 documentation misses the `,render` part and you fixed my problem!